# Node Js Session management demo

Tags: node.js, session, express

Can anybody tell me how to make session variable in Node Js and how to browse that.
Actually I am working on Node Js and with Express

```
    exports.setSession=function(req,res){
req.session.user = 'demo';
//console.log("adding to session " + JSON.stringify(user));
console.log("SessionS-"+req.session.user);
    };


   exports.get_session = function(req, res){
console.log("SessionFun-"+req.session.user);
 };
```

I did this way but getting undefined value in session var

```
 Output:         
     SessionS-demo
     SessionFun-undefined
```

Comment: Try to use [connect middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) to manage your [session](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html). It's much more convenient way to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks but It uses connect i have to use express

Comment: Express is based on a connect, so when you use express you already have all connect middleware. I'll prepare the example for you in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is based on a connect middleware, so you can reuse connect session implementation rather than writing you own. Example code you can find below.

```
var http = require('http')
  , express = require('express')
  , app = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: '1234567890QWERTY'}));

app.get('/set',function(req, res){
    req.session.user = { name:'andbas' };
    res.send('Session set');
});

app.get('/get',function(req, res){
    res.send(req.session.user);
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});
```

This code set the session user variable when you make a `GET /set` call, and post it back to you when you do the `GET /get`. 
Just try it.

Mistake you do in your own code is that you only modify the req variable, which node `http` module create for each request. It's not the place where you could hold the data. Instead of this you need to user HTTP headers to setup the key, which will be used to recognize the user and store it data on server (I greatly simplified the concept to make it more understandable). You can review the code in the [connect session](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) to understand how it works.

Comment: Can you help for getting data out from callback function that am facing from long time ie. res.('data',function(data){ console.log(data);  })

Comment: Jayant, I don't think that I understand your question.